# ASP.NET MVC / Mysterious characters in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have deployed a website in ASP.NET MVC (version 5.2.3.0) and i am facing a strange problem, sometimes there are characters which goes in the URL like, for example :
www.website.com/(X(1)S(3hfps41rchxt45wwrsn4o5bi))/RestOfRoute instead of www.website.com/RestOfRoute

It happens randomly and the mysterious string always matches (X(1)S(*)).

After searching on stackoverflow, I found that it could be related to session-less cookie, but my website does not use it.
Here is an extract of the Web.config that maybe could help :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="<url>" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Does anybody know what is the source of this problem ?

**EDIT 1 :**

"system.web" block of the Web.config

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="<url>" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>

  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048576000" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Which `web.config` is it? `Views/Web.Config` or not?

Comment: No, it is the Web.config at the root of my website

Comment: Have you tried to add the part in my answer to your `web.config` with the `False` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am pretty sure, your `web.config` included this.
This makes session per tabs. Each tab will have unique identifier, and with the help of this identifer the server will know which tab is requesting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there is no block "sessionState" in my Web.config. I post the "system.web" block in my question.

Comment: @GérardLambert Then, could you please add it with tha value `false`?

Comment: There was a comment <!--<sessionState mode="inproc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="60" />-->, I removed it and it seems I no more have the problem :-/ After that, I included <sessionState cookieless="false" />. It seems to be still OK. I will check the logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC in two hours. If I do not have X(1)S(*) in the logs, then I will accept your answer !

Comment: @GérardLambert You don't need to add these part with `false` value, if it isn't included in your config. I just said that, just in case.

Comment: It seems to be good now. In the logs, I have X(1)S(*) for some javascripts only (maybe caused by cache) ? I remain confused because the only thing I have done is removing the commented sessionState section and adding <sessionState cookieless="false" /> (which, according to you, is not necessary). But many thanks for your help !

Comment: @GérardLambert Glad it helped.
But, IMHO it must alo work: `<sessionState mode="InProc"`. Because, their default value is false.